# iOS - Single bar view (or "chart")

Tags: ios, graph, charts

I absolutely love the way Activity Monitor app shows disk and memory usage.
Is there any library to do this? Alternatively, how could I build something similar?
Here is the image : 
[image]
<sub>(source: [appchronicles.com](http://appchronicles.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/Screen-Shot-2012-10-30-at-10.36.04-AM.png))</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is old, but I created a similar component: https://github.com/mrojas/MRBarView
It's a work in progress, soon I'll add more options to customize it.